# Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (20.0.6)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I get the following error stack trace when trying to navigate to a screen that uses Firebase Realtime Database for the second time after running the application on my android device.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (20.0.6). If you are not already on the latest version of the Firebase SDKs, try updating your dependencies. Should this problem persist, please file a report at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidPlatform$1$1.run(AndroidPlatform.java:96)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8168)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: listen() called twice for same QuerySpec.
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.persistence.NoopPersistenceManager.runInTransaction(NoopPersistenceManager.java:131)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.addEventRegistration(SyncTree.java:549)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.keepSynced(SyncTree.java:857)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.keepSynced(Repo.java:772)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.keepSynced(Repo.java:767)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$4.run(Query.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934): Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: listen() called twice for same QuerySpec.
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.ConnectionUtils.hardAssert(ConnectionUtils.java:67)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.listen(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:391)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo$5.startListening(Repo.java:206)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.setupListener(SyncTree.java:918)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree.access$1000(SyncTree.java:79)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree$13.call(SyncTree.java:645)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.SyncTree$13.call(SyncTree.java:550)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3934):        at com.google.firebase.database.core.persistence.NoopPersistenceManager.runInTransaction(NoopPersistenceManager.java:126)[1]][1]
```

My pubspec.yaml file:
[image: pubspec.yaml]

My Flutter doctor output:
[image: Flutter doctor]

Comment: Logs and code should be posted as text not screenshots.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) are you using VSCode for this? 2) have you run flutter pub upgrade and made sure your dependencies are up to date?

Comment: Maybe you should try follow this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3643